# Запрос Curl через PHP с сертификатом ГОСТ2012

Tags: php, nginx, curl, openssl, гост

пожалуйста не пинайтесь, сам я не девелопер но задачку надо решить))

Имею сервер на Centos 8 в котором собран curl и openssl с поддержкой криптографии ГОСТ2012.
Когда отправляю запрос `curl -v -k https://гос_сайт_рф.рф/ --key /cert/my_key.key --cert /cert/my_cert.cer` без проблем выдает информацию. Сам сертификат Гост2012, сгенерирован на этой же машине. Был создан PHP код, который должен висеть на apache или nginx сервере, и обрабатывать запросы с сертификатами гост.
Не знаю как реализовать сам сервер с этим кодом PHP, чтоб работал с сертификатам  гост. буду рад любой помощи и совету.

сам код index.php

> ```
> <?php
>
> $ch = curl_init();
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://ссылка_сервера_X");
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
>
> // Receive server response ...
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
>
> $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
>
> curl_close ($ch);
>
> //$data = $server_output;
> //echo $data;
>
> // Further processing ...
> if ($server_output == true) {
>     $response = $server_output;
> } else {
>     $response = "no data response";
> }
> echo $response;
> ```

Comment: Какие ошибки вы получаете?

Answer (score 0):

Вам понадобится пересобирать из исходников libcurl с поддержкой SSL бэкэнда OpenSSL, а в сам OpenSSL добавлять gost-engine

Мануал по сборке гуглится по запросу: "Как добавить поддержку ГОСТ 34.10 2012 в CentOS/Redhat 7"

При этом для использования OpenSSL бэкэнда в libcurl необходимо его установить перед инициализацией:

```
curl_global_sslset(CURLSSLBACKEND_OPENSSL....
```

https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_global_sslset.html